# In design, EditText error "Render problem" in android

Tags: android

i have error with EditText is "render problem" in design in android when i drag and drop "Plain Text" from Palette to frame design. But when i run app, app run and show normally in genymotion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.122" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: error render problem in design]

[image: app run normally]

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i solved this by change rendering engine (below the message Rendering problem). Sry. forgot to take a screenshot :P
[image: до]

[image: после]

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to let android studio instruct you what could be possibly done a manner; efficient & standardized for developer by pressing **alt+enter** or following **tip icon** & applying the changes.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to always remember is that "when you are using drag and drop feature in the android studio you need to `extract string resources` for every component

see this image of my code
[image]

In this code, the text view type is not specified in most cases like you there is an error for `Hardcoded string`. try to use `ALT+Enter` for specifically required operation on this particular component.